# Program crashes after input a String using Malloc

Tags: c, string, pointers

The program crashed after entering a long string. I think the program cannot handle a large amount of string entered by the user. Can you help me whats wrong on my code?

a simple C-program that counts the vowel and consonants in a string using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * sEnteredString= NULL;
    int i;
    int sizeString;
    int vowel=0;
    int consonants=0;

    printf("A program that counts the number of vowels and consonants in a string\n");
    printf("Enter a string:\t");
    sEnteredString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(sEnteredString));
    scanf(" %s",sEnteredString);

    if (sEnteredString==NULL)
    {
        printf("OUT OF MEMORY\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sizeString=strlen(sEnteredString);

        for (i=0; i<sizeString;i++)
        {
            if((sEnteredString[i] == 'A') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'a') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'E') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'e') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'I') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'i') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'O') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'o') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'U') || \
               (sEnteredString[i] == 'u'))
            {
                vowel ++;
            }
            else
            {
                consonants ++;
            }
        }
            printf("Entered vowel: %d \nEntered constants: %d\n", vowel, consonants);
    }

    free(sEnteredString);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry it should only be C.

Comment: `sEnteredString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(sEnteredString));`: is only allocating 4 or 8 bytes. You have to specify a size.

Comment: ``sEnteredString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(sEnteredString));`` That's the problem. ``sEnteredString`` is a pointer so it's going to allocate memory based on the size of that pointer

Comment: @Asesh Please make an answer, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: As you are saying *after entering a long string* and using `int sizeString;` are you sure `int` can store the length

Answer (score 1):

why are you (wrongly) allocating dynamic memory for this:

```
sEnteredString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(sEnteredString));
```

where `sizeof(sEnteredString)` is the size of the char pointer (which is usually 4 or 8) ? so too short when entering a string like "hey! waffles!".

when you can do:

```
char sEnteredString[100];
```

then

```
scanf("%99s",sEnteredString);
```

so you auto allocate your string and there's a safety in case someone enters a too big string.

Important: don't `free(sEnteredString)` in the end

Aside: use `toupper` along with a `switch/case` statement to avoid all those ifs. And remember to count consonants, not chars that aren't vowels (like spaces, punctuation, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that you are allocating memory for only 8 chars or 4 chars based on the size of pointer. (varies due to 32-64 bit systems). It is unlikely that your  string would hold in 4 or 8 char's with the NUL terminating character. And then you try to read string larger than this , you have illegal memory access...accessing something you didn't allocate. You clearly have undefined behavior.(In your case program crashed).

Second problem is your checking of `malloc` shouldn't it be before you use it? Yes..but you didn't follow that.

```
sEnteredString = malloc(50);
if( sEnteredString == NULL){

 /* error */
}
else{
   if( scanf("49%s",sEnteredString)!= 1){
     // error
   }
   // at this point you are happy that sEnteredString points to
   // a nul terminated char array 
   // strlen can be used safely here.
   size_t sizestring  = strlen(sEnteredString);

}
...
free(sEnteredString);
```

Yes another thing is you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` - it's redundant.

Also note I have used `size_t` to hold return value of `strlen`.

And yes easy way to check what you did will be

```
   if( strchr("aAeEiIoOuU",sEnteredString[i]) != NULL ){
     // you got a vowel
   }
```

Also keep in mind one thing `strlen` is supposed to get a pointer to a null terminated char array. If you don't provide that you will have undefined behavior.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * s;

    s = malloc(50);  
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        perror("Malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A program that counts the number of vowels and consonants in a string\n");
        printf("Enter a string:\t");

        if(scanf("%49s",s)!= 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
            free(s);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        size_t sz = strlen(s);
        size_t vowel = 0,consonants = 0;
        for (size_t i=0; i<sz; i++)
        {
            strchr("aAeEiIoOuU",s[i]) ? vowel++ : consonants++;
        }
        printf("Entered vowel: %zu \nEntered constants: %zu\n", vowel, consonants);
    }
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```